# The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag cfmail - Error

Tags: coldfusion, timeout

I have a wrapper page throwing this error at the cfmail tag which is used to send the cfcatch dump error email. The wrapper page is calling a custom tag which is a scraping file. The Wrapper is scheduled as a job to run everyday, and the timeout occurs in a similar fashion. I have enough timeout setting on the wrapper and the custom tag. Any ideas on what can be done here?

[image]

Comment: what part of the code is actually taking a long time?

Comment: The custom tag has bunch of cfhttp calls which scrapes pages. It is not clear from the error though

Comment: Setting a timeout on a custom tag seems odd.  In any event, you did not mention the timeout for the scheduled task.  That's certainly worth a look.

Comment: The wrapper file does have a timeout on it. How should I add the timeout for the scheduled task?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think the timeout of your wrapper file will supercede that of the scheduled task.  Having said that, adding it to the scheduled task couldn't hurt.  To do so, log in to the ColdFusion administrator page and find your task.  There will be an html form where you can set a number of things, such as the timeout.

Comment: if you add `requestTimeout=99999` to your scheduled task url that will override settings anywhere else from what I recall.

Comment: @MattBusche 99999 seconds ~= 28 hours, maybe not the best value in case there is actually something wrong with the script preventing it finishing in a reasonable time

Comment: As @MattBusche's first said, you need to figure out what in there is taking so long, maybe add some cflog statements around those cfhttp calls.  Once you have that information, you can start figuring out where the time is going.